# what should be the correct format of using anotation @repository in DAO layer?

Tags: java, spring, dao

is it like `@Repository`  or `@Repository("DAOname")` ?

which is appropriate? why?

and

one major doubt regarding update and delete method in DAO layer!
Is it safe to have logics in DAO layer?

i mean,
for eg:
DAO layer

```
@Transactional
public void deleteMethod(List list)
  {
  for(list)
  {
    deleteNamedQuery(list);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? if yes, how did you do it?

Comment: i put my delete iterating logic in service layer , instead of DAO layer, as it is not a good and safe practice to put iterating logics in DAO layer.

Comment: Please, add your answer in order to close this topic

Answer (score 3):

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO {}
```

in this case the bean if you perform a `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package" />` will be named "userDAO"

```
@Repository("userRepository")
public class UserDAO {}
```

instead in this case will be named "userRepository". In few words are appropriate both solution, depends how you use it.

I suggest you not to add business logic within your DAO to maintain the Separation of Concern.
[See this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), in addition

> A data access object (DAO) is an object that provides an abstract
>   interface to some type of database or other persistence mechanism.

[See this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)

Answer (score 0):

Service Layer(put the Iterating logic in service )

```
@Override
    public void deleteCheckedItems(List<Integer> selectdIdForDeletion, String userid) {
        try
        {
            for(Integer id:selectdIdForDeletion)
            {
                dao.deleteMethod(id, userid);  // called DAO method for delete
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.info(e);
        }

    }
```

DAO Layer(removed the iterating delete logic )

```
@Transactional
public void deleteMethod(String id,String userid)
  {

    deleteNamedQuery(id,userid);

}
```